# Is there something like csv or json but more graphical and better to read for humans?

Tags: json, xml, csv, yaml, human-readable

For example CSV and JSON are human and machine readable text formats.

Now I am looking for something similar even more `graphical` for table data representation.

Instead of:

```
1,"machines",14.91
3,"mammals",1.92
50,"fruit",4.239
789,"funghi",29.3
```

which is CSV style or

```
[
 [1,"machines",14.91],
 [3,"mammals",1.92],
 [50,"fruit",4.239],
 [789,"funghi",29.3]
]
```

which is JSON style, and I am not going to give an XML example, something similar like this is what I have in mind:

```
   1 | "machines"| 14.91
   3 | "mammals" |  1.92
  50 | "fruit"   |  4.239
 789 | "funghi"  | 29.3
```

There should be reader and writer libraries for it for some languages and it should somehow be a standard. Of course I could roll my own but if there is also a standard I'd go with that.

I have seen similar things as part of wiki or markup languages, but it should serve as a human easily editable data definition format and be read and also written by software libraries.

That's not exactly what markup and wiki languages are for. What I am looking for belongs more to the csv,json and xml family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would checkout textile. It has a [table syntax](http://redcloth.org/hobix.com/textile/#tables) almost exactly like what you described.

For example, the table in your example would be constructed like this:

```
|   1 | machines | 14.91  |
|   3 | mammals  |  1.92  |
|  50 | fruit    |  4.239 |
| 789 | funghi   | 29.3   |
```

An alternative (albeit not optimized for tabular data), is [YAML](http://yaml.org/), which is nice for JSON-ish type data.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could also look at the CSV editor's i.e.

- [CsvEd](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/)
- [CsvEasy](http://csveasy.com/)
- [ReCsvEditor](http://recsveditor.sourceforge.net/)

There whole purpose is to display CSV and update data in a more readable Format. The ReCsvEditor will display both Xml and Csv files in a a similar format.

Google CsvEditor, you will find plenty